# How to correctly reference a collection of Aggregates?

Tags: entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

With DDD there is a distinction between an Entity and an Aggregate. In EFCore I’m happy with the approach of using private collections and using a specification pattern to populate child entities when required. Similarly Julie Lerman and others have written really good articles on adapting EF for DDD.

An Aggregate, as opposed to an Entity, can/should only hold an Id reference to another Aggregate, rather than navigation property, which we can use to pull back via it’s Repository with a `GetById()` call.

What is more of a problem is determine how an Aggregate could hold a collection of Id references to a collection of Aggregates and how this can be achieved with Entity Framework?

Typically you’d set it up with navigation properties and foreign keys.

```
public Class Foo
(
  public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
)
```

However, what I’m looking for to be in keeping with DDD is.

```
public Class Foo
(
  public List<int> BarIds { get; set; }
)
```

What I don’t want to have is the `Bar` aggregate knowing that it has a relationship to `Foo` as it could be referenced by many other Aggregates.

Is it perhaps the case that you can’t have a collection of Aggregate Ids on an Aggregate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to correctly reference a collection of Aggregates?

You reference an aggregate by its id. So you reference a collection of aggregates by a collection of ids (each id references an aggregate).

> how an Aggregate can hold an Id reference to another Aggregate

It's simple: the id of the another aggregate is a field in the aggregate that holds the reference.

> how this can be achieved with Entity Framework?

I don't know EF, but an aggregate holds an id reference the same way it holds any other field of the aggregate.

I don't know the reason of the struggle.

Say you have 2 aggregates: Foo and Bar, so that Foo references Bar (Foo ==> Bar). If the client of Foo wants to get the instance of Bar referenced by an instance of Foo:

```
String aFooId = ...
Foo aFoo = fooRepository.getById ( aFooId );
String aBarId = aFoo.barId();
Bar aBar = barRepository.getById ( aBarId );
```

Comment: Cheers, I’ve edited my question as it is more of an implementation issue with EF to handle the distinction between collections of Entities and collections of Aggregates.

Comment: As l said in my answer, in DDD you have to reference another aggregate by its id, so referencing a collection of aggregates should be done by holding a collection of their ids. Whether EF allows you or not implementing such a list of ids, I don't, but that's the way it would be done. An alternative if you cannot hold list of ids, is to hold just the id on the other side of the relationship, and perform a query to retrieve the list of ids every time you need them

Comment: I'm surprised that this has been selected as the correct answer because as far as I can tell, this in no way answers the question, which is specifically about how to implement persistence of a list of aggregate IDs in Entity Framework, which usually requires a navigational property as a collection of the full aggregate - not ID.

Comment: "I don't know EF", "I don't know the reason of the struggle." Well, that's because EF needs a navigation property to automatically get the data that is required (the list of IDs of the other aggregate) And you shouldn't use reference to another aggregate but that's what EF enforces you to do.